# Is it possible to get access to local variable of method in runtime with Reflection API or with some other things?

Tags: java

Actually here is me code

```
public class Example {

    public void method () throws InterruptedException {
        int var = 100;        
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        // do some logic
    }    
}
```

I need to know is the local variable `var` so incapsulated like wise people say.

Comment: what you want to achieve? where you want to access local variable?

Comment: Like I said in Runtime. In general of cause.

Comment: why don't use access it with the name of variable `var`? Why you need reflection?

Comment: The question actually was about security and encapsulation.

Comment: A debugger can, so it's possible, take a look at java debugger source

Comment: But how about a production code? In this case I can't use debug.

Comment: Aaron, I think we have a language problem; many readers are not sure what your question is. If you give some more information about what you are trying to do (or what you are trying to prevent someone else form doing) it would help people answer you. (for example, are you trying to read a hidden variable in a class/library that you don't have source code for?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variables only exist while the method is running, and there's a separate copy in each activation of the method.  Since the reflection API doesn't reflect method activations, you can't get methods' local variables via reflection.

Comment: Ok. Maybe there are some other approach to get this var? If method is executing - for example - 10 mins, can I get access to his local var from the outside of him? I mean maybe there are some dirty hack to connect to JVM and get local variable?

Comment: As others have mentioned in comments, it's accessible via a debugger, if the JVM is running in debug mode.  And of course, someone with the right skills could just look through the running JVM's raw memory and find the value that way.  But there's no normal, programmatic way for Java code to access other methods' local variables.